# Can I solve $\partial_t(\partial_t +a ) W(x,t) = (\partial_t + b)\hat{L} W(x,t)$ using the solution $\partial_t W_0 = \hat{L}W_0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have a challenging partial differential equation which is second order in time:
$$\partial_t(\partial_t +a ) W(x,t) = (\partial_t + b)\hat{L} W(x,t)$$
Here $L$ is some linear operator which involves $x$ only, not $t$.

I know the solution $W_0$ to a simpler problem with only one derivative:
$$\partial_t W_0 = \hat{L}W_0$$

Is there any way I can use $W_0$ to obtain $W$?
So far I attempted the convolution ansatz
$$W(x,t) = \int_0^t ds K(t-s)W_0(x,s).$$
Using the resulting identity
$$\partial_t W = K(0)W_0(x,t) + \hat{L} W$$
Does lead to an interesting integral equation that gives the kernel function $K$ in terms of $W_0$, although this violates the assumption that $K$ does not depend on $x$.

Is there any means by which I can use the solution to the simpler problem to understand the more challenging problem?

Comment: This is tagged with perturbation theory. You say you have a solution to a 'simpler problem', do you actually mean to the zeroth order problem? If so, where is your perturbation series? I do not see any mention of a small parameter either. Or perhaps this tag is a mistake?

Comment: "Is there *any* means by which I can use the solution to the simpler problem" . One could imagine a Dyson series-like approach on the original equation. Any constructive thoughts?